# Xcode 6.1.1 crashed changing TableView to Static Cells

Tags: xcode, uitableview

I am trying to create a Table View Controller in my storyboard and when I change from "Dynamic Prototypes" to "Static Cells" Xcode stops responding until it eventually crashes.

What I tried so far:

- Re-installing Xcode;
- Clear Xcode folders under `~/Library` (including DerivedData);
- Creating in a new project (still crashes);
- Ask a colleague to create a Table View Controller with static cells in the same project. He can do it on his computer. I can see the Table View on my computer and even edit rows, but I cannot add sections.
- Tried both Swift/Obj-C projects, with or without Core Data;

I am using XCode 6.1.1 (6A2008a), the same as my colleague.

Please help! Thanks!

Comment: I'm having the same issue. seems to be an xCode problem.

Comment: This still exists in 6.2 beta 3. I didn't see any bug fixed. not at all, everyone of them still exists. wtf apple?

Comment: Fixed in Version 6.3.2 (6D2105). Update Xcode!

Comment: @MichaelEnriquez I don't have access to that computer anymore. Can't test it. You're probably right, though ;)

Answer (score 1):

Yes , I have faced similar problem .please try with  Xcode 6.3.x or later version .

Answer (score 0):

Not a fix but may help some.  I noticed this was only happening to me when I had two windows of my current project open.  Was reworking a storyboard, so I had the old and new side by side.  When I closed the windows of my project that I was not currently editing, Xcode did not crash.  With more than one window open, editing a Static Table View would crash Xcode EVERY time.

Comment: It didn't work for me. Xcode stalls/crashes even when I have only one window and one tab.

Answer (score 0):

I found a temp Fix. I also noticed that my dock isn't working fine (I can drag and drop things into it or in it). So I rebooted the mac and this fixed the dock problem, I tried quickly in Xcode and it worked. I guess it's something with Mac OS not just Xcode

Comment: I don't think this is related to my issue. In any case, it didn't work.